# AngularJS ng-pattern behaviour

Tags: ng-pattern

I have a **ng-pattern** to enforce a particular format (for instance, IP v4 address):

```
<input ng-model="ip" 
       ng-pattern="/(([2][0-5]{2}|[2][0-4]\d|[01]?\d{0,2})\.){3}([2][0-5]{2}|[2][0-4]\d|[01]?\d{0,2})/">
</input>
```

The data comes from the DB but let's say that the requirement evolved and now **IPv6** should be stored. I would have expected changing the regular expression but it removes the content of the input!
Check this plunker (where you can see the losing-content effect): http://plnkr.co/edit/UPrU35

It is kind of the same thing as switching an input to required, I simply need users to comply to the new rules.

Question:

How should one proceed to apply ng-pattern but still keep the ng-model binding? 
*(I want the form input to be invalid but no at the cost of losing its former content)*

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand what exactly you require , however i see a problem in the code ,

You are using the same model on 3 different input tags , which is not advisable. 
  I would suggest using something like this ,

```
<label>No pattern</label>
  <input ng-model="ip4.test1"></input><br>

  <!-- Pattern 1 -->
  <label>Pattern (IP v4)</label>
  <input ng-model="ip4.test2" ng-pattern="/(([2][0-5]{2}|[2][0-4]\d|[01]?\d{0,2})\.){3}([2][0-5]{2}|[2][0-4]\d|[01]?\d{0,2})/"></input><br>

  <!-- Pattern 2 -->
  <label>Changed pattern (IP v6)</label>
  <input ng-model="ip4.test3" ng-pattern="/([A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}::?){1,7}[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,4}/"></input><br>
```

By doing this , you can avoid the losing other input fields , plus you get the ng-pattern validation.

And in your JS file , you can use them something like this ,

```
$scope.ipv4 = {

 test1 : <value> , 
 test2 : <value>,
 test3 : <value>};
```

And access its value like this ,

```
var temp = $scope.ipv4.test1;
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: So, whenever I need to change validation rules (using ng-pattern) on the frontend side, you suggest I place 2 inputs which each pattern and map the one with the new pattern into DB?

Comment: Depends on what u want to achieve , if u want to just change the ng-pattern validation and dont care about losing the old value , then you can do that using a single <input> tag , and provide a variable to ng-pattern instead of giving the pattern inline.